# Set to src of img from dataDirectory file path

Tags: image, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to set a `src` of a `<img>` on a html from a string path of a file.

The path is obtained from `cordova.file.dataDirectory` cordova plugin on `Ionic2` (`Typescript`) and looks like:

***EDIT TO SHOW MY CODE:***

**This is the relevant part of the profile.ts code**

```
...
import {Camera} from "ionic-native";
...
import {API} from "../../services/api";
import {ImageAdquistionService} from "../../services/imageAdquisition.service";
...
import {Network,File} from 'ionic-native';




declare let cordova: any;


@Component({
  selector:    'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})

export class ProfilePage implements OnInit{


  connected:boolean = false;

  imagePath: string = "./assets/img/pio.jpg";
  userInfo: User = new User();


  constructor(

              private api:API,
              private imageAdquistionService: ImageAdquistionService,
              ){

    //seleted tab by default
    this.tabs="info";

    this.connected = Network.type !== "none";

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.localStorageService.getUserInfo().then(user => {
      this.userInfo = user;
      if (this.userInfo.imagenPerfil !== "defAlert") {

        File.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory,this.userInfo.profileImage).then(result => {
         console.log("exist")
          this.imagePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + this.userInfo.profileImage;
         })
         .catch(error => {
         console.log("not exist " + JSON.stringify(error))
         })
      }
    });

  }

  presentImageOptions(){

    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title: 'Select an option',
      buttons: [
        {
          icon: 'camera',
          text: 'photo',
          handler: () => {

            let navTransition = actionSheet.dismiss();
            navTransition.then(() => {
              this.imageAdquistionService.getANewImage(Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA).then(imageData => {
                if(imageData.success){
                  this.uploadImage(imageData.fileName, imageData.filePath);
                }
                else{this.presentToast(imageData.message)}
              })
            });
            return false;
          }
        }, {
          icon: 'image',
          text: 'Gallery',
          handler: () => {

            let navTransition = actionSheet.dismiss();
            navTransition.then(() => {
              this.imageAdquistionService.getANewImage(Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY).then(imageData => {
                if(imageData.success){
                  this.uploadImage(imageData.fileName, imageData.filePath);
                }
                else{this.presentToast(imageData.message)}
              });
            });
            return false;
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Close',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
  }


  uploadImage(fileName: string, filePath: string){


    this.presentLoadingCustom();
    this.localStorageService.getAccessToken().then(token  => {

      this.api.uploadFile(fileName,filePath).then(result =>{
        this.loading.dismissAll();
        console.log("uploaded OK);

        this.userInfo.profileImage = fileName;
        this.imagePath = filePath;

          this.api.updateUserPreferences(this.userInfo,token).then(result =>{
            if(result.success) {
              console.log("updated ok");

              this.presentToast("image updated succesfully");
            }
          });

      })
        .catch(error => {
          this.presentToast(error.message)
        })
    })

  }

}
```

**This is the relevant code of imageAdquisitionService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {LocalStorageService} from "./localStorage.service";
import {Platform} from "ionic-angular";
import {Camera, File, FilePath} from "ionic-native";
import {API} from "./api";


declare let cordova: any;

@Injectable()
export class ImageAdquistionService {


  constructor(private storage: LocalStorageService,
              public platform: Platform,
              private api:API) {
  }


  getANewImage(src):Promise<any>{
    let options = {
      quality: 60,
      sourceType: src,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true
    };


    return Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

      // Special handling for Android library
      if (this.platform.is('android') && src === Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {


        return FilePath.resolveNativePath(imageData)
          .then(filePath => {

              let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
              let currentName = imageData.substring(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imageData.lastIndexOf('?'));

                return this.storage.getUserInfo().then(user => {

                    return this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName(user._id)).then(copyResult => copyResult);


            });

            }, (error) => {
              // Handle error
              return {success: false, message: error.message};
            }
          );
      } else {

        let currentName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        let correctPath = imageData.substr(0, imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        return this.storage.getUserInfo().then(user => {

            return this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName(user._id)).then(copyResult => copyResult);

        });
      }
    }, (error) => {
        // Handle error
        return {success: false, message: error.message};
      }
    )
  }
  // Create a new name for the image
  createFileName(id:string) {
    let d = new Date(),
      n = d.getTime(),
      newFileName =  n + ".jpg";

      newFileName = id + "_" + newFileName;
      return newFileName;


  }

// Copy the image to a local folder
  copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName):Promise<any> {

    return File.copyFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(success => {

      console.log("response of copy " + JSON.stringify(success));
      return {success: true, fileName: newFileName, filePath: this.pathForImage(newFileName)};

    }, error => {
      this.api.logIonicView("Error while storing file " + error.message);

      return {success: false, message: error.message};
    });
  }

  // Always get the accurate path to the apps folder
  public pathForImage(img) {
    if (img === null) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return cordova.file.dataDirectory + img;
    }
  }

}
```

**This is the relevant code of the api service**

```
uploadFile(name:string, path:string):Promise<any>{

    let options = {
      fileKey: "file",
      fileName: name,
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
      params : {'fileName': name}
    };

    let fileTransfer = new Transfer();

    // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image

    return fileTransfer.upload(path, this.urlBase + "upload", options)
      .then(data => {
        console.log("message on filetransfer "+ JSON.stringify(data.response));

        data})
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

**And this is the relevant code of the html code**

```
<ion-item no-lines class="item-bar-profile">
      <ion-avatar>
        <img class="centered" src="imagePath" (click)="presentOptions();">
      </ion-avatar>
</ion-item>
```

This is a example with the default imagepath hardtyped with :

this.imagepath =  "./assets/img/pio.jpg"

[image]

An this is a example when programatically change the path to

this.imagepath = file:///data/user/0/com.ionicframework.myionicproject494629/files/58db7e92be26f32d4c8c01d2_1491989021049.jpg

[image]

thanks

Comment: Hello, I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Hello, I have same problem on ios, any solution for ios?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem. I realized that though I was running on an android device, I was running it live in ionic which doesn't work with cordova plugins. So instead of doing `ionic cordova run android -l -c` I had to run the command `ionic cordova run android`.

Answer (score 0):

This is Wrong anyway `[src]="this.imagepath"`.No need to use `this` here.

You can try as shown below.

***file.html***

```
[src]="imagepath"
```

Comment: You're right, it was a type error. I've updated the original post with a example of image path and more info. When I change programatically the default image to the new path it renders to trasparent

Comment: You just need to do a simple thing here.See which part of this URL will generate the desired image (`file:///data/user/0/com.ionicframework.myionicproject494629/files/58db7e92be26f32d4c8c01d2_1491989021049.jpg`).According to that just do string manipulation and make your working URL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `this` inside `[src]="this.imagepath"`.

I think

```
[src]="imagepath"
```

or

```
src={{imagepath}}
```

would work just fine.

**NOTE** : This works if `file:///usr...package....image.jpg` is a valid path.

Comment: You're right, it was a type error. I've updated the original post with a example of image path and more info. When I change programtically the default image to the new path it renders to trasparent

Comment: Whatever your path <url> is, try `<img src="<url>" />` e.g. `<img src="file:///data/user/0/com.ionicframework.myionicproject494629/files/58db7e92be26f32d4c8c01d2_1491989021049.jpg">`. If it renders, it's a valid image path. And it will render. Otherwise it will not.

Comment: I've tried to hardcode the path and still not showing. `File.checkFile` return that the file exist. Would be any influence that is a ion-avatar?

Comment: Where are you getting the url from?

Comment: Also, can you check it on an android device than an emulator. The hardcoding part. Also, check the url you are mentioning actually exists at the given directory in your phone.

Comment: In `OnInit` method on my ts file I form the url from `cordova.file.dataDirectory` + a property stored on a variable. If I hardcode the path on `src`(html) the image stills trasparent. however if I change the `src` in `OnInit` method the image shows the broken image icon. This is strange because is exactly the same path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141537/discussion-between-sagar-kulkarni-and-hanzo).